# Firebase push notification

Tags: javascript, firebase

estoy desarrollando un proyecto web en donde deseo implementar las notificaciones push de firebase, para lo cual antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body implemento el siguiente codigo:

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script> 

        <script>

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: ""
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        console.log("messaging: ",messaging);

        function IntitalizeFireBaseMessaging() {
            console.log("IntitalizeFireBaseMessaging")
                messaging
                    .requestPermission()
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log("Notification Permission");
                        return messaging.getToken();
                    })
                    .then(function (token) {
                        console.log("Token : "+token);
                        // document.getElementById("token").innerHTML=token;
                    })
                    .catch(function (reason) {
                        console.log(reason);
                    });
            
                }

            messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
                console.log("payload: ",payload);
                const notificationOption={
                    body:payload.notification.body,
                    icon:payload.notification.icon
                };

                if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
                    var notification=new 
     Notification(payload.notification.title,notificationOption);

                    notification.onclick=function (ev) {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        window.open(payload.notification.click_action,'_blank');
                        notification.close();
                    }
                }

            });
IntitalizeFireBaseMessaging();
        </script>
```

y en la raiz del sitio tengo el fichero firebase-messagin-sw.js, que contiene el siguiente codigo:

```
                importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.0/firebase-app.js');
            importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
                // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            var firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: " ",
                authDomain: " ",
                projectId: " ",
                storageBucket: " ",
                messagingSenderId: " ",
                appId: " "
            };
            // Initialize Firebase
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            const messaging = firebase.messaging();

            messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
                console.log("payload",payload);
                const notification=JSON.parse(payload);
                const notificationOption={
                    body:notification.body,
                    icon:notification.icon
                };
                return 
      self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title,notificationOption);
            });
```

Lamentablemente el evento onMessage nunca se lanza y por ende nunca llega la notificación, esta notificación la envío tanto desde firebase como también de una app que tengo en php con curl, alguna idea de que puede estar ocurriendo?, porque tampoco tengo algún error que me indique un posible problema. Se ejecuta sin problemas la función IntitalizeFireBaseMessaging() pero no así los evento.